# Lower bound for $|\cos z|$ for $|z|=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show these inequalities:

For $|z|=1$
 $$\frac{1}{3} \lt |\cos z| \lt \frac{5}{3}$$
Here is what I have so far:

Let $z = x + i y$

$\cos z=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{ix}e^{-y}+e^{-ix}e^y\right)\implies|\cos z|\le\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{-y}+e^y\right)\le e$

And for the left side I have $\frac{e-\frac{1}{e}}{2}$.

I cannot seem to find a way to show these tighter bounds.

Comment: $|a+b|\neq|a|+|b|$.

Comment: I would suggest substituting $z=e^{i\theta}$

Answer (score 2):

$|\cos z|^2=(e^{2y}+e^{-2y}+2\cos(2x))/4$ and we want to prove it is less than $\frac{25}{9}$, or equivalently $e^{2y}+e^{-2y}+2\cos(2x)<100/9$. Since $x^2+y^2=1$ both $x$ and $y$ are forced in the range $[-1,1]$. The maximum of $e^{2y}+e^{-2y}$ is achieved when $y=1$ and the maximum of $\cos(2x)$ is achieved in $x=0$, hence LHS$\leq e^2+1/e^2+2<(2.8)^2+1/4+2=10.09<11<100/9$. So $|\cos z|<5/3$ for $|z|=1$.
For the other inequality we have to prove $e^{2y}+e^{-2y}+2\cos(2x)>4/9$. The minimum of $e^{2y}+e^{-2y}$ is achieved for $y=0$ and the minimum of $2\cos(2x)$ is achieved when $x=1$, so we have to prove $2+2cos(2)>4/9$. $cos(\alpha+\pi/2)=-sin(\alpha)$ and in our case $0<\alpha<\pi/4$ since $\pi/2+\pi/4>2>\pi/2$, so we have to prove $2(1-sin(\alpha))>4/9$ or $sin(\alpha)<7/9$, but in that range sin is increasing so $sin(\alpha)<sin(\pi/4)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}<7/9$, hence we are done.

Comment: What about the other side of the inequality?